# How to Add new permission to Laravel project in a production environment

Tags: laravel, permissions

In a Laravel project, we use the spatie/laravel-permission package

At the beginning of the project, we added all the desired permissions and roles to the project with Seeder

Now we need to add new permissions again

If we add the permissions to the same file as before, it will cause all the previous codes to be executed again and the database will be damaged.

I could create a Seeder class every time I want to add a new permission, but I don't think that's a good solution.

Do you have a better solution?

It is also important to mention that I think I should have the list of permissions in the code so that the rest of the team can have the same permissions after running Seeder.

Comment: Make admin frontend for permission management. Or insert directly in database.

Comment: But I need to have the list of permissions in the code, so that the rest of the team can have similar permissions with the help of running Seeder.

Comment: Make a class with permissions consts(or enum) And hm, console command that fetch all permissions from database and compare with that enum. If found new - add to database, if found deleted - delete from database.

Comment: Creating migrations  for every new permissions and roles is not a good idea.  You can use the same seeders and ignore if exists for old data.

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple syncronizer after see your question - this is useful in one of my projects :)

This implementation is not very good and must use `Enum` - but in my projects i have old php version.

Create a file with permissions - you can use this constants in code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Authorization;

class Permissions
{
    public const PERMISSION_1 = 'permission_1';
    public const PERMISSION_2 = 'permission_2';
}
```

And console command for sync:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Authorization\Permissions;
use Illuminate\Console\Command as ConsoleCommand;
use ReflectionClass;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

class SyncPermissions extends ConsoleCommand
{
    protected $signature = 'permissions:sync';
    protected $description = 'Sync permissions to DB from const file';

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass(Permissions::class);
        $actualPermissions = $reflection->getConstants();
        $currentPermissions = Permission::query()->pluck('name', 'id');
        $toDelete = $currentPermissions->filter(fn($name) => ! in_array($name, $actualPermissions));
        $toCreate = collect($actualPermissions)->filter(fn($name) => ! in_array($name, $currentPermissions->toArray()))->values();
        if($toDelete->count() > 0){
            $this->info('Deleted ' . $toDelete->count() . ' permissions');
            Permission::query()->whereIn('id', $toDelete->keys())->delete();
        }
        if($toCreate->count() > 0){
            $toCreate->each(function($name) {
                Permission::create(['name' => $name]);
                $this->info('Created ' . $name . ' permission');
            });
        }
        $this->info('Ok');
    }
}
```

When run `php artisan permissions:sync` - all permissions that are not listed in the consts - will be deleted, and all new permissions will be added to database.